# Customizing .NET forms design

Tags: winforms

Just like Google Chrome's application header how can I change my .NET windows applications header from

[image]

to something like this

[image]

I couldn't find any properties in VS2K10 to modify the style of header and/or form outer frame.

Comment: FormBorderStyle = None.  And a helluvalot of code to make the fake caption work like the regular one and look good.  Helps if you have a bunch of programmers and (especially) designers.

Comment: @HansPassant - Man you rock!!! this is what I want. I can create my own header all I need is to hide the predefined one! and you helped me in making it. If you are interested write the same as answer below so that I can mark it as best answer :o)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there's nothing to personalize your form headers from 'the out of the box' VisualStudio.
There are component vendors like **Infragistics** or **DevExpress** that give you this feature with their suite and there are also some free useful idea [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24942/Adding-custom-skins-for-Forms-in-VB-Net).
However, I think that the burden of managing so many details is impractical.